# Public key storage by full nodes

Tags: bitcoin-core, blockchain.info, bitcoin-core-development

How many public keys on an average, do the full nodes store, in order to validate/authenticate the transactions they receive?

Comment: I assume bitcoin full node: the full node stores all pub keys, that were used to sign a trx (that found it's way in a block), in the data structure in the home dir. Why? Because all vlid trx are part of a block, and all blocks since the genesis block form the block chain. So there is even more than pub keys stored on your harddrive of a full node.

Comment: Chapter 5 of Andreas book "mastering bitcoin" explains tx handling, and developper info can also be found here; https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-guide#transactions